# The particular integral of a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Consider the following 2nd order differential equation, $$\frac{\text{d}^2 z}{\text{d} t^2} + \omega^2 z = C \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$$where $z$ is complex, and $C$ and $\omega$ are unknown real constants.

Now that I am about to find the particular integral. I tried $z=A\text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$, so $\frac{\text{d}^2 z}{\text{d} t^2}=-A\omega^2 \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$, and the differential equation becomes $-A\omega^2 \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t} + A \omega^2 \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t} = C \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$, which implies $C=0$. That is obviously nonsensical.

[Edit: I am sorry. I mixed some $z$s and $t$s at first.]

So, could someone please explain where I am wrong or what alternative method(s) should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, the right side is in resonance with the left side, the exponential factor is a root of the characteristic polynomial of the differential operator on the left. In these cases you have to add a monomial factor $t^m$ corresponding to the multiplicity of the characteristic root (in the non-resonance case $m=0$, as the factor is not a root, so also that case fits in).

So try again with
$$
z=At\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\omega t}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The problem is easier if you switch variables to make
$$-\frac {t''}{[t']^3}+\omega^2 z=C e^{i \omega z}$$ Reduction of order $p=t'$ to get
$$-\frac {p'}{p^3}+\omega^2 z=C e^{i \omega z}\implies p=\pm \text{something}$$

Not sure about the remaining.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\text{d}^2 z}{\text{d} t^2} + \omega^2 z = C \text{e}^{\text{i}\omega t}$$
$${e}^{-i\omega t}z''\color{red} {- i\omega z'{e}^{-i\omega t}+iz'\omega {e}^{-i\omega t}}+\omega^2 z {e}^{-i\omega t} = C $$
$$({e}^{-i\omega t}z')'+(iz\omega {e}^{-i\omega t})'= C $$
$$({e}^{-i\omega t}z'+iz\omega {e}^{-i\omega t})'= C $$
$${e}^{-i\omega t}z'+iz\omega {e}^{-i\omega t}= Ct+C_2 $$
$$({e}^{i\omega t}z)'={e}^{2i\omega t}( Ct+C_2 )$$
Integrate.
$$z(t)=A \sin (\omega t)+B \cos (\omega t)+\dfrac {C}{2i \omega }te^{i \omega t}+\dfrac {C}{4\omega ^2}e^{i \omega t}$$